# Implicit file extension using fopen in C++

Tags: c++, string, fopen

I'm working on a project where I'm required to take input from a file with an extension ".input". when run, the user gives the filename without the file extension as a command line argument. I then take that argument, argv[1] and open the file specified but I can't get it to work without the user typing in the entire filename

for example:

user enters> run file.input
//"run" is the executable, "file.input" is the filename

user is supposed to enter> run file

how do I get this file extension implied when using this code:

```
fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

I tried using a string, setting it to argv[1] and then appending ".input" to it but fopen won't accept that string.

Comment: Can you show us specifically what you tried? That should work. Also, any reason you're using `fopen` and `FILE*` rather than `ifstream`?

Comment: What you need is elementary string operations, which any better C++ tutorial should explain. However, it wouldn't explain file operations using `fopen()`, so chances are that you either use C or that the source you are learning from is bad.

Comment: [Give the docs for std::string::c_str a read.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: my teacher suggested fopen(), but he does tend to talk more about c than c++ so perhaps that's why.

Comment: you need a new variable for the filename.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: You don't. A temporary will do just as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I can't say for certain what went wrong, but I suspect you did something like this:

```
string filename = argv[1];
filename += ".input";

FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r"); // <--- Error here
```

The issue here is that the C++ `std::string` type is not a `char *`, which is what's expected by `fopen`. To fix this, you can use the `.c_str()` member function of the `std::string` type, which gives back a null-terminated C-style string:

```
FILE* f = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r"); // No more errors!
```

As I mentioned in my comment, though, I think you'd be better off just using `ifstream`:

```
string filename = argv[1];
filename += ".input";
ifstream input(filename);
```

There's no longer a need for `.c_str()`, and you don't need to worry about leaking resources. Everything's managed for you. Plus, it's type-safe!

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. I'm not used to having to deal with reading files and I'm used to just using plain old strings.